# Exercise at home

Tags: home-exercise

I'm currently losing weight and at some point I would like to build up my muscular tone. Sadly, due to university I can't go to gym. Are there useful exercises I could do at home? I'm 1.75m, currently weigh 86kg and I used to play tennis.

Comment: Huh. Where I'm from universities are the most likely places to have free gyms.

Comment: There are quite a few questions already on bodyweight and home exercising, I encourage you to search the site.

Comment: This is an odd question. You know you can just buy weights right? And push ups are free.